# Maximal common subgraph preserving labeling

Tags: graph, graph-algorithm

Given two graphs G1 and G2 on the same set of nodes V, I want the maximal common subgraph preserving the labeling of the nodes.

I know that the general MCS problem is NP-Hard, is still that with this restriction?
Is there a specific algorithm for that case?

Thanks

Comment: Sorry, but if `G1=(V,E1)` and `G2=(V,E2)`, isn't the MCS simply `GM=(V,EI)` where `EI` is the intersection of `E1` and `E2`? I mean, the reason MCS is NP-Hard is because of the isomorphism problem. If you've already got a vertex correspondence, there's not more problem.

Comment: No, it isn't. Take the example:

G1
1-2
1-3

G2
1-2
1-3
2-3

The intersection will be 
1-2
1-3

But it is not the MCS (in its strong definition)

Comment: Why not? It is a subgraph of G1, and it is a subgraph of G2, and it can't get any larger because it is already all of G1.

Comment: Yes, but it is not in general an induced sub-graph

Comment: @imabug. That it has to be an *induced* subgraph was not mentioned in your question, and it is also not required in the normal problem definition of MCS.

Answer (score 0):

It is not entirely clear to me what the problem is exactly. In particular, what does "on the same set of nodes" mean?

But: if the general problem is NP-hard (which, depending on what the problem is exactly, it may or may not be), then the problem which includes labels should also be NP-hard, because we can reduce the original problem (without labels) to the problem with labels by just giving every node in G1 and G2 the same label.

If you want a more clear answer, you should define your question more precisely:

- What is a graph? (Is it directed or undirected, is it a multigraph or a simple graph, etc. How are labels assigned to the nodes of the graph?)
- What is your version on the MCS problem? (In the usual definition of the problem there is an isomorphism involved)?
- What do you mean with "on the same set of nodes"? (Does it only mean that the two graphs have the same number of nodes, or does it mean that the MCS uses the same nodes in both graphs? In the latter case, the problem is not NP-hard.)

Comment: "The same set of nodes" means the two graphs have the same nodes. Node A in G1 is node A in G2, node B in G1 is node B in G2 and so on